# Meteor - Run code on DOM render\re-render

Tags: meteor

HTML

```
<template name='sometpl'>
  <select>
  <option>day</option>
  <option>night</option>
  </select>
  {{#if day}}
    <div class='ui popup' data-popup='I'm awake!'>day</div>
  {{#if night}}
    <div class='ui popup' data-popup='I'm asleep'>night</div>
</template>
```

coffee

```
Template.sometpl.helpers
  day:-> if $('select').val()=='day' then true
  night:-> if $('select').val()=='night' then true

Template.sometpl.onRendered ->
      $('.ui.popup').popup()
```

This code `$('.ui.popup').popup()` initializes popups on respective elements (semantic-ui).The problem is that it's ran only once on tpl render thus affecting only this node: `<div class='ui popup' data-popup='I'm awake!'>day</div>`.
When I choose `night` this code `$('.ui.popup').popup()` is not run leaving newly rendered node `<div class='ui popup' data-popup='I'm asleep'>night</div>` without popup.
Moreover, when I select `day` back again - it doesn't have popup this time! As it has invoked rendering of entirely new 'day' div, and not the old one.
What can be done here?

Answer (score 1):

Try making a component out of your day and night divs:

```
<template name="popup">
   <div class='ui popup' data-popup='{{text}}'>{{day}}</div>
</template>
```

Its javascript:

```
Template.popup.onRendered(function() {
    this.$('.ui.popup').popup()
});
```

Then you can do this:

```
{{#if day}}
    {{>popup text="I'm awake" day="day"}}
{{/if}}

{{#if night}}
    {{>popup text="I'm asleep" day="night"}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Thank you. But can this be done w\o including another template? Maybe I oversimplified my example, but I literally have hundreds of such `select`s and it'd be a pain to maintain hundreds of corresponding tpls for them, as you might imagine.

Comment: Assuming the popups all follow a similar format you only need one additional template as shown above. Just change the `text` and `day` to `popupText` and `text` if that makes it clearer, and then call the template with those variables where ever you need the popup...

Comment: @avalanche1 The alternative is to use `this.autorun(function() { $(".popup").popup() });` in your `onRendered` block. You also have to add in something reactive. With your helpers you directly query the select field but if you use something reactive (and you should anyway) and query this reactive variable in the `autorun` block it should update when you change the select fields.

Comment: @Akshat here they gave me an advice to use `ReactiveVar`, I've made an example pad with it, but it doesn't seem to work. https://forums.meteor.com/t/run-code-on-dom-render-re-render/4901/2 Can you give it a look and maybe fork with `this.autorun`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to use `Tracker.afterFlush` and `Tracker.autorun`.
Complete [solution](http://meteorpad.com/pad/XWAYxJyeo5qTck39H/dom%20re-render).
Thanks to guys [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-run-code-on-dom-render-re-render/4901).